# finding all checkboxes that are NOT checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I wanted to select all checkboxes that are selected, I could do this.

```
$('#mydiv input[type=checkbox]:checked')
```

Is there a similarly simple syntax that lets me select all the checkboxes that are NOT selected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hiya yep:  **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/usvrb/

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

**quote**

> ```
>   The .not() method will end up providing you with more readable selections than pushing complex selectors or variables into a :not()
> ```
>
> selector filter. In most cases, it is a better choice.

Hope this helps, :) cheers!

Answer (score 3):

```
 $('#mydiv input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)')
```

Answer (score 2):

You won't believe it.

```
$('#mydiv input[type=checkbox]').not(':checked')
```

**EDIT**: Stackoverflow management, whats going on with the nuts CAPTCHA? Every single answer today requires me to enter a CAPTCHA code?